# Can someone help me make a JFormattedTextField that works with my code?

Tags: java, numbers, jframe, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I am looking for someone to help me make a JFormattedTextField. I want to to ONLY accept numbers (0-9). When a user inputs a invalid input (EX: "a"), it will not let it be inputted! I've tried other pre-made source codes but I don't know where to place it in my code! And they always cause errors...

Here is my code...

```
private void followerPrompt() {
    JFormattedTextField followerPrompt=new JFormattedTextField("0");  
    JFrame followerPromptWindow=new JFrame("Enter the number of followers you have:");  
    followerPromptWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,1,1));  
    followerPromptWindow.add(followerPrompt);
    followerPromptWindow.setResizable(false);
    followerPromptWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    followerPromptWindow.setLocation(500, 400);
    followerPromptWindow.setVisible(true);  
    followerPromptWindow.setSize(promptWindowWidth * promptWindowScale,promptWindowHeight * promptWindowScale);  
    JButton followerPromptWindowButton = new JButton("Next Step");
    followerPromptWindow.add(followerPromptWindowButton);
    followerPromptWindowButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {         
            followerInput = followerPrompt.getText();
            System.out.println("Follower Input: " + followerInput);
            likePrompt();
            followerPromptWindow.dispose();
        }
    });
}
```

As you might see, I already have it set (and imported) to JFormattedTextField. But I don't know how to make it actually work. If someone can give me a code that was placed into my code and sent back, that would be great!

Thanks,
Maxie_Z :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of requirements, I'd ditch the JFormattedTextField (you don't want to format but to filter) and use a normal JTextField, with a custom [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) on its document. Create a custom filter, and override its `replace` and `insertString` methods to only accept digits. You can also beep/change the textfield's background momentarily when a non-digit is entered.

Comment: While this is an OK answer to the question *as stated*, I feel this is a textbook example of an XY problem

Comment: What's an "XY problem"?

Comment: Essentially - I'm suspecting that the "Accept only 0-9 and no other input" is OPs way of solving the *actual* problem of "Allow only numbers". And solving the latter is *a lot* easier and cleaner.

Comment: @Maxie_Z - see, e.g., here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html

Comment: Can you make me one with my code... Sorry! I am new to Java and need a little bit of help! Thanks!